# Xubuntu 12.04 Changing midnight commander colours

Tags: colors, midnight-commander

I used to be able to change the colour set for midnight commander, by changing the "colour string" in the ini file.  It seems now that in xubuntu (Xfce4) mc's colour set is determined by some other means.  How do I revert to the previous scheme, with the option of using my own colour strings?

Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Im using xfce4-terminal and had same issue (caused by default color scheme), to  fix that must edit each color, one by one in MENU Edit/Preferences/Colors/Palette

or edit the config file located at:

`~/.config/Terminal/terminalrc`

but... what may be 'pretty colors'?
see http://blogs.n1zyy.com/andrew/2009/02/02/tango-color-scheme-for-xfce-terminal/
some good defaults here:

```
ColorForeground=White
ColorBackground=#323232323232
ColorPalette1=#2e2e34343636
ColorPalette2=#cccc00000000
ColorPalette3=#4e4e9a9a0606
ColorPalette4=#c4c4a0a00000
ColorPalette5=#34346565a4a4
ColorPalette6=#757550507b7b
ColorPalette7=#060698989a9a
ColorPalette8=#d3d3d7d7cfcf
ColorPalette9=#555557575353
ColorPalette10=#efef29292929
ColorPalette11=#8a8ae2e23434
ColorPalette12=#fcfce9e94f4f
ColorPalette13=#72729f9fcfcf
ColorPalette14=#adad7f7fa8a8
ColorPalette15=#3434e2e2e2e2
ColorPalette16=#eeeeeeeeecec
```

Comment: This color scheme is much better than the default one! Thanks. However the blue background of mc should be darker, IMHO. I have noted that in my `terminalrc` file there are 3 other `Color` values between `ColorBackground` and `ColorPalette1`.  I have preserved them.

Answer (score 0):

To extend on Wenceslao's answer, [here](http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=190192.0]) one can find settings from good ol' Ubuntu `11.10` :

```
[Configuration]

; FontName=Consolas 12
; for XUbuntu 12.04, I have fount that the above font does not go well with the rest,
; so it'd better be the "default" one for the installation:
FontName=Droid Sans Mono 12

MiscAlwaysShowTabs=FALSE
MiscBell=FALSE
MiscBordersDefault=TRUE
MiscCursorBlinks=FALSE
MiscCursorShape=TERMINAL_CURSOR_SHAPE_BLOCK
MiscDefaultGeometry=80x24
MiscInheritGeometry=FALSE
MiscMenubarDefault=TRUE
MiscMouseAutohide=FALSE
MiscToolbarsDefault=FALSE
MiscConfirmClose=TRUE
MiscCycleTabs=TRUE
MiscTabCloseButtons=TRUE
MiscTabCloseMiddleClick=TRUE
MiscTabPosition=GTK_POS_TOP
MiscHighlightUrls=TRUE
ShortcutsNoMenukey=TRUE
ShortcutsNoMnemonics=TRUE
ColorForeground=#0000e8e80000
BackgroundMode=TERMINAL_BACKGROUND_TRANSPARENT
```

Now comment out (with `;`) every other line, don't forget to save the file -- and you're good to go )

PS. A direct [link](http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?PHPSESSID=86g8jab154alcg58as6ovpndj7&topic=190192.msg1426492#msg1426492) to the thread message (that is more vulnerable to changes, I suppose).